# Setting AM maximum and PM minimum dates in only time UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I set 10 PM as a minimum hour and 4 AM as a maximum hour in a only time mode UIDatePicker?

Comment: swift? objective c?

Comment: nvm this is **Duplicate**, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494174/minimum-and-maximum-date-in-uidatepicker

Comment: Yeah, seems like there is a Swift answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: I added a day component to the date, so 4 AM is one day after 10 PM. The problem is that I want to show it in only time mode date picker and it let's me pick only the the time between 10PM and 12AM and not until 4AM.