# SBDatePicker Its posssible to set minimum date and maximum date in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am new for developing the ios application, I have used SBPickerSelector in Cocapods framework for Selecting datePicker.
whether If possible to set the MinumDate and MaximumDate???

Comment: where you downloaded the `SBDatePicker` can you show the apth

Comment: yes I have dowloaded using Cocapods.. http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SBPickerSelector/1.0.9/index.html

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: func ShowDatePicker() {
 let picker: SBPickerSelector = SBPickerSelector.picker()
 picker.delegate = self
 picker.pickerType = SBPickerSelectorType.Date
//picker.doneButtonTitle = "Done"
//picker.cancelButtonTitle = "Cancel"
  picker.onlyDayPicker = true;
        //picker.datePickerType = SBPickerSelectorDateType.Default
        picker.defaultDate = NSDate()
        let point: CGPoint = view.convertPoint(view.frame.origin, fromView: view.superview)
        var frame: CGRect = view.frame
        frame.origin = point
        picker.showPickerIpadFromRect(frame, inView: view) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
let picker: SBPickerSelector = SBPickerSelector.picker()

//Minimum Date
picker.datePickerView.minimumDate = NSDate(); // A date

//Maximum Date
picker.datePickerView.maximumDate = NSDate(); // An other date ;
//or picker.setMaximumDateAllowed(NSDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what do you get from using `SBDatePicker`, it look like they simply wrap the original class `UIDatePicker`.

The problem of using this kind of wrappers is that they don't always have the full feature set of the original class and you count on their developers to keep up with Apple changes (which they don't).

If you **simply use `UIDatePicker`** you can set `maximumDate` and `minimumDate`, just like you asked.

Check out the [UIDatePicker Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/)

And here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494174/minimum-and-maximum-date-in-uidatepicker) of setting the minimum and maximum dates