# UIDatePicker minimal value?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

In Swift, I have a `var datePicker = UIDatePicker()`. I'm trying to set the `datePicker` to have a minimum value of Jan, 1st, 1920 (I want a range from Jan, 1st, 1920 to current date. I read how to set the `maximumDate` of the `UIDatePicker`, that was easy, but I couldn't find how to set the minimum to a specific date. I read that it should be `datePicker.minimumDate` but I'm not sure how to set the exact date from above. Suggestions?

Comment: have you try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494471/6638533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create appropriate date components

  ```
  let components = DateComponents(year: 1920, month: 1, day: 1)
  ```
- Create a date from the components

  ```
  let minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
  ```
- Set the minimum date

  ```
  let picker = UIDatePicker()
  picker.minimumDate = minimumDate
  ```

Comment: Yeah, that works! Thanks. I'll accept your answer in a bit (apparently I cant in the next 8 min) 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSDateFormatter as the following:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("1920-01-01")

let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.minimumDate = date
```

Comment: The date format string is wrong: YYYY is the "week-based" year, and DD is the day of the year.