# How to set maximum date in UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create `UIDatePicker` in my project which maximum date should be that of yesterday instead of current date. Is there a way to set selected date as yesterday instead of selecting current date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum and maximum date in UIDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494174/minimum-and-maximum-date-in-uidatepicker)

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't read the documentation for `UIDatePicker`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `maximumDate` property of your date picker.

```
let yesterdayDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
yourPicker.maximumDate = yesterdayDate
```

Comment: did solve your problem?or still seeking for solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to achieve this

```
let calender = Calendar.current
    let date = Date()
    let finalDate = calender.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.day, value: -1, to: date)

    if let FinalDate = finalDate{
        yourPicker.maximumDate = FinalDate
    }
```