# setMaximumDate is not working in UIDatePickerModeDate UIDatePicker ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to implement UIDatePicker for Birthday, and I want to limit Maximum date to today.

Here is my code:

```
UIDatePicker * datePicker =  [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 50, 200)];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

`setMaximumDate` is totally not working in `UIDatePickerModeDate` mode for `UIDatePicker` in `ObjectiveC`

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you setting your maxdate correctly as in this example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064864/uidatepicker-setting-maximum-and-minimum-dates-based-on-todays-date

Comment: Could you show how are you getting maxDate?

Comment: Hi CCastro, this link is not working for me. I already searched everything. please help

Comment: Hi Jose Quintero, I set my maxDate to [NSDate date]. But still no luck. please help

Answer (score 0):

**Set a maximumDate of one month from now**

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date] ;
// Get current NSDate without seconds & milliseconds, so that I can better compare the chosen date to the minimum & maximum dates.
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents* nowWithoutSecondsComponents = [calendar components:(NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:now] ;
NSDate* nowWithoutSeconds = [calendar dateFromComponents:nowWithoutSecondsComponents] ;
//  UIDatePicker* picker ;
picker.minimumDate = nowWithoutSeconds ;

NSDateComponents* addOneMonthComponents = [NSDateComponents new] ;
addOneMonthComponents.month = 1 ;
NSDate* oneMonthFromNowWithoutSeconds = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:addOneMonthComponents toDate:nowWithoutSeconds options:0] ;
picker.maximumDate = oneMonthFromNowWithoutSeconds ;
```